# Java on calling copy constructors

Tags: java, methods, copy-constructor

I have a question about java copy constructors.
I am writing a program where I have a private final instance variable and i'm writing an add method that calls 2 values for real numbers as well as imaginary numbers.  How do I go about writing this method?

My return statements are not being too effective.
So any tips?

Comment: Post some code, please.  This makes no sense as written.

Comment: now please read your question and try to see whether a person that does not know your code can understand the situation. I, for one, cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy constructor is a c++ (and, perhaps, other languages) concept.  A kind of close equivalent in Java is the Cloneable Interface.  From the API JavaDoc:

*A class implements the Cloneable interface to indicate to the Object.clone() method that it is legal for that method to make a field-for-field copy of instances of that class.*

To make a "copy" of an object call the .clone() method.  For example:

```
String schmarr = "schmarr";
String schmarrClone = schmarr.clone();
```

check out clone() [at this link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) (this is the java 5.0 reference).